# How to fire multiple API calls asynchronously at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

Basically I have a screen that calls multiple APIs at `componentDidMount`, and each and every API will fire a network request along with a callback, something as below

```js
componentDidMount() {
    new APIManager.fetchBooks(this.handleBooks);
    new APIManager.fetchAuthor(this.handleAuthor);
    new APIManager.fetchShops(this.handleShops);
}

...

handleBooks = (result) => {
  this.setState({ books: result });
}
...
```

And basically all the `fetch` methods works pretty similarly, it accepts a single parameter which is a callback from the component, pseudocode as below

```js
export async function fetchBooks(callback) {
  const result = await callNetworkAPI();

  callback(result);
}
```

This was working fine on both Android and iOS at react-native v0.53 but it's not working anymore at v0.59.10 on iOS.

What's happening now is that, `fetchBooks`, `fetchAuthor` and `fetchShops` will all still be triggered but `this.handleBooks`, `this.handleAuthor` will no longer be triggered. It's like they lost their cursor.

I've made it work such that all API calls has to be using `await`, something as below

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const books = await APIManager.fetchBooks();
  const authors = await APIManager.fetchAuthor();
  const shops = await APIManager.fetchShops();


  this.handleBooks(books);
  this.handleAuthors(authors);
  this.handleShops(shops);
}
```

And of course updates to my `APIManager` as below:

```js
export async function fetchBooks() {
  const result = await callNetworkAPI();

  return result;
}
```

Its working fine, but all 3 API calls cannot be asynchronously anymore because I made it await for the previous API call before proceeding. I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle my problem? Or I'm totally on the right track?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for multiple requests in parallel:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const [books, authors, shops] = await Promise.all([
    APIManager.fetchBooks(),
    APIManager.fetchAuthor(),
    APIManager.fetchShops(),
  ]);

  this.handleBooks(books);
  this.handleAuthors(authors);
  this.handleShops(shops);
}
```

This however waits for all 3 requests to be completed before calling `handleBooks` / `handleAuthors` / `handleShops`.

If you want them to call their handle method directly after they completed, you could use `.then()` on the individual fetch calls:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await Promise.all([
    APIManager.fetchBooks().then(this.handleBooks),
    APIManager.fetchAuthor().then(this.handleAuthors),
    APIManager.fetchShops().then(this.handleShops),
  ]);
  // All fetch calls are done now
  console.log(this.state);
}
```

(this works because `async` functions always return a promise)

About your problem with the fetch calls, you might be affected by this `react-native` bug:
[Multiple fetch request starts to not resolve or reject promise](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21862)
According to the github issue page, it should be fixed in [version `1.2.1`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/issues/10#issuecomment-465922423) of `react-native`.

Comment: can you explain why the callback way not working here?

Comment: @CuongTranDuc not really, for that we would need a bit more context what the actual error was you were getting and what `callNetworkAPI()` does to fetch the results. Your callback code looks ok, apart from the `new` before APIManager that shouldn't be necessary in your code example.

Comment: @Turtlefight: Truth is I'm not sure why it wasn't working with the callback way. As mentioned, it is working fine on `Android` but not working on `iOS` anymore

Comment: @Isaac you might be running into this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21862 it seems to be a known bug in `react-native`

Comment: @Turtlefight: Gotta work on my Googling skills. Thanks for your elegant answer anyway!

Comment: @Isaac Glad i could help :) It should be fixed in version 1.2.1 of `react-native`, so updating it should hopefully fix the problem :)

Comment: Multiple axios calls within one component did not work for me. Sometimes the request was mapping to the wrong props after receiving - inside mapStateToProps. Sometimes only one call etc. After separation of each axios call into a separate component and doing the imports, everything works fine. The solution, I would do is to either work on the api model and fetch the whole model-data within one call since they need to be related with pk and fk, or separate components for reliability and maintenance.

Answer (score 8):

Hope so It will help you for multiple API calls simultaneously.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
Promise.all([
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'),
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
]).then(function (responses) {
    // Get a JSON object from each of the responses
    return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }));
}).then(function (data) {
    // Log the data to the console
    // You would do something with both sets of data here
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    // if there's an error, log it
    console.log(error);
});
},[])
```